# MYSQLI: Get result of query from Ajax call to HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to get the result of a database query, which will almost always contain more than one row of data, from an Ajax call in an HTML file, back to the HTML file so that I can display it.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Function for getting data from database
        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_data.php",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Finished!");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
</body>
    <!--I'd like to put a table of data here-->
</body>
</html>
```

`get_data.php`:

```
<?php
    include "action.php";

    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE;

    //Connecting to database
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    //Check database connection
    if($mysqli === false) {
        die ("\nCould not connect:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo nl2br("\nConnected successfully! Host info: " .   mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
    }

    echo executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli);
?>
```

`action.php`:

```
 <?php
    define("SERVER_NAME", "localhost");
    define("USERNAME", "root");
    define("PASSWORD", "");
    define("TABLE", "data_set");

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    //Check database connection
    if($mysqli === false) {
        die ("\nCould not connect:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo nl2br("\nConnected successfully! Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
    }

    //Function to execute database queries
    function executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli) {
        if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query)){
            echo nl2br("\n\nQuery executed successfully: $sql_query");
        } else {
            echo nl2br("\n\nERROR: Could not able to execute $sql_query. " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }
    }
?>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the result of the query from `action.php` to 'get_data.php`, back to the original Ajax call from`index.html`so that I can build my table. I've tried just using`echo` with the result of the query, but that did not work because there was an error for the conversion of an object to a string.

Comment: Can you confirm that the you are getting what you want in the PHP file, but it just isn't being displayed on `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any return value from your executeQuery function. The *mysqli_query* function returns a *mysqli_result* object, or the boolean *false* if anything fails. You can use this *mysqli_result* object to get the data which you require and put it into an array. This array should be encoded into a json response, which is a format which Javascript understands.

So for example:

```
function executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli) {
    $rows = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);

    if ($result === false) {
        // Do something if anything goes wrong here like throwing an exception
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Then you can call this function to get the data and convert it to json as follows:

```
$rows = executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

This is the most basic of basic ways, however this exact implementation is not recommended. Outputting the real column names for a table is a vulnerability because everyone can see them, I'd loop through them and change them before using *json_encode*.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and parsed the JSON to change them, but so far I can only use it from `get_data.php` where the function call is made. Is there a way to get the JSON encoding back to the HTML page where the Ajax function was called?

Comment: So when you open get_data.php you get a json string, but the Ajax call won't interpret it into something usable? Perhaps calling *$.Json* instead​of *$.ajax* will fix that. There is also a way by setting the response type of get_data to *application/json* but this should be the easiest way.

Answer (score -1):

You defined **TABLE** but where is your **DATABASE** name? You can't just write down `echo` in every places. You have to use `mysqli_fetch_array` function to get the result as array and then send that as json. I just fixed the whole code in one script, guess, it will help.

```
<?php
define("SERVER_NAME", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("DATABASE", "YOURDATABASE");
define("TABLE", "YOURTABLENAME");

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

//Check database connection
if ($mysqli === false) {
    die ("\nCould not connect:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Function to execute database queries
function executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);
    if ($result) {
        //You have to run mysqli_fetch_array to get real data as array
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
}

$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE;

//Connecting to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

//Check database connection
if ($mysqli === false) {
    die ("\nCould not connect:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    //echo nl2br("\nConnected successfully! Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
}


//after getting the result send output to brower with json encode and then from your ajax response
// You can handle json data easily.
// And for json response you can't just write echo from everywhere in script. Send either die on failure or result on success
$result = executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
exit();
```